# Как задать before div"у

Tags: wordpress

Осваиваю wordpress, по макету нужно добавить иконку номеру, подскажите как мне это сделать с помощью псевдоэлемента before. фреймворк layers

Comment: Добавьте пояснение, код или что-нибудь, чтобы понять, чего именно вы хотите.

Comment: Я уже разобрался, в библиотеке можно взять путь к картинке и вставить куда надо. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress тут, в общем, ни причем. Делается примерно так:

```
.icon_twitter:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 14px;
  content: "\f09a";
  color: gray;
}
```